# button only clickable on lower half html

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons on my web page and they are only clickable on the lower half of them. I saw this post [Anchor working only in the lower half of the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575329/anchor-working-only-in-the-lower-half-of-the-button), but the solution was to change the styling on them. I don't have any styling on mine.

The buttons:

```css
    div.buttons{
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="buttons">
         <button type="button" ng-click='test()' class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="testactive">Run Test</button>
         <button type="button" ng-click='stoptest()' class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="testinactive">Stop Test</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's in the `btn-success` class CSS?

Comment: @sideroxylon it's bootstrap class

Comment: @user137717 Can you make fiddle of it ?

Comment: @squiroid would you need the javascript too? I don't think I can post that publicly.

Comment: Ok, But I didn't find any mistake in this code.According to me it will work find on complete button.

Comment: @squiroid I made this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mnkodxmx/ The weird part is the button is clickable from anywhere in the fiddle and the appearance is also different. This is not what it looks like in my application. I did take the bootstrap blog template. possible there is button styling in that. I will look into this.

Comment: You Need to set line-height property of button.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan That worked, but can you make an answer with more detail in it? I am using the number option to make it a multiple of the current font size, but I'd be interested in knowing how to always make it the full height of the button. I tried several different values and above a certain number any value makes the full button active, but I'd like the full button to be active for any size button in case i change it later or make other buttons.

Comment: @user137717 I have just added an answer .. Please read it and I am sure it will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, normally when we use button tag or hyperlink tag its line-height is fine as default.

But when we add some style and font size some big or small then we need to set line-height ...

```
button{font-size:20px; line-height:30px;}
```

it will be working fine.

So try it and I am sure it will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

instead try this

replace `button` as `input`

```
<div class="buttons">
         <input type="button" ng-click='test()' class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="testactive">Run Test</button>
         <input type="button" ng-click='stoptest()' class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="testinactive">Stop Test</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: can someone explain why this got a downvote? I'd like to know if it's a bad practice etc...